# Change class property to default value

Tags: angular, typescript, optimization

In typescript I have a property inside a class, which should be true if the onEdit function is called and false otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(0: void {}

selectedStudent: Student
@Output() editStudent = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Output() deleteStudent = new EventEmitter<any>();

onEdit(student: Student)
{
    this.selectedStudent = student;
    this.editStudent.emit(student);
}

onDelete(student: Student): void
{
    this.deleteStudent.emit(student);
}

editedStudent = (student: Student) => this.selectedStudent?.id === student.id;

}
```

and html:

```
<table>
    [Highlighted]="editedStudent"
</table>
```

I tried setting
`this.selectedStudent = null;`

But that is not the best solution since if I have 15 functions in my class, then I have to write the same line 15 times. Cand I do something in the constructor? Or use another life cycle hook?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: The respective property "editedStudent" is activated when the edit function is called and  once it becomes true, it never changes to false. It should change to false when the onDelete function is called.

Comment: Great, and what prevents you from doing it inside the onDelete func ?

Comment: This is just a small sample from my code, I have more functions in the same class, like add,get. So I want to avoid adding an extra line in all these functions, I'm wondering if I can do it in the constructor or somewhere else.